# Access and Delete a row in one query in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room Database to make a database to store information in a table. I want to access one entry from the table and delete the same entry without the need to call two functions.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM history_packet_table ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1")
fun get(): HistoryPacket?

@Query("DELETE FROM history_packet_table ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1")
fun delete()
```

I want these two operations to happen only by calling `get`. Is there a way?

Comment: Question: Why do you want to delete on the same read operation?

Comment: @MD   To avoid any inconsistencies in the database. The read and delete operations should be atomic for this implementation.

Comment: Execute both statements in a single transaction.

Comment: @Shawn Hey, can you help me with that? I don't have much knowledge of SQLite.

Comment: Also note that using `LIMIT` in a `DELETE` requires a custom version of sqlite3.c built from the master source after passing `--enable-update-limit` to `./configure`, and compiling it with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` #defined. (I have no idea if the version of sqlite that comes with Android was built this way) See https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit

Comment: Start with https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html if you're not familiar with transactions.

Comment: @Shawn I want to delete the element with the smallest timestamp value. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Several. Something like `DELETE FROM history_packet_table WHERE timestamp = (SELECT min(timestamp) FROM history_packet_table)` would be a typical approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can add the following to the Dao :-

```
@Transaction
fun getAndDelete() {
    get()
    delete()
}
```

Obviously you can call the function what you wish. However, the get seems to be useless as it is.

So you may want something like :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM history_packet_table WHERE timestamp = (SELECT min(timestamp) FROM history_packet_table)")
fun get() :HistoryPacketTable

@Query("DELETE FROM history_packet_table WHERE timestamp = (SELECT min(timestamp) FROM history_packet_table)")
fun delete() :Int

@Transaction
fun getAndDelete() :HistoryPacketTable {
    // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
    var rv: HistoryPacketTable = get()
    val rowsDeleted: Int = delete()
    if (rowsDeleted < 1) {
        rv = HistoryPacketTable();
        //....... set values of rv to indicate not deleted if needed
    }
    return rv
}
```

- Note as LIMIT on delete is turned off by default, the queries can be as above, this assumes that timestamp is unique otherwise multiple rows may be deleted, in which case the Dao could be something like

:-

```
@Delete
fun delete(historyPacketTable: HistoryPacketTable) :Int

@Transaction
fun getAndDelete() :HistoryPacketTable {
    // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
    var rv: HistoryPacketTable = get()
    val rowsDeleted: Int = delete(rv)
    if (rowsDeleted < 1) {
        rv = HistoryPacketTable();
        //....... set values to indicate not deleted
    }
    return rv
}
```